# How to work with the versioning system in godoc?

Tags: git, go, version-control

I'm working on a project in Go while attempting to learn about version control and git and I was quite surprised that godoc automatically generates a nicely formatted web page for your package.
However, I'm having trouble with the versioning, as every single update of my package I push to my repo is instantly updated and given a new version (such as  `v0.0.0-20211229051600-f8ba7fec14c7`) in godoc, which does not match the version tags I use with git.

How can I work with the versioning here? Is there a way to sync with git (I assume not, but it'd be cool)?

Comment: What you see is a [pseudo-version](https://go.dev/ref/mod#pseudo-versions). Once add a git tag to your module, the module will use that version instead.

Comment: That's really helpful, thank you! I suppose I was impatient to post this.